# creating .so file at specific location

Tags: makefile

I am creating a makefile and learning to create a shared library in it.
What I actually want is to create a .so file in same directory as of the .o files. The directory I have is

src-->

```
 abc.c
 xyz.c
 pqr.c
 makefile
```

linux --->

```
  bin--->

        abc.o
        xyz.o
        pqr.o
```

MakeFile I have created so far is given below . I just want a .so file created in bin directory, but .so file is not getting created somehow
maybe my Makefile is very basic, but can you please help me with this.
Thanks in advance.

```
.PHONY: all

CC = gcc
LIB_PATH= ../unix/bin
SRC_DIR = $(wildcard *.c)
OBJ = $(SRC_DIR:.c=.o)
INCLUDES = ../unix/private_include/
OBJ_DIR = $(wildcard $(LIB_PATH)/*.o)

# ALL TARGET
all: $(OBJ)

%.o: $(SRC_DIR)
    $(CC) -fPIC -I$(INCLUDES) -c $< -o $(LIB_PATH)/$@

%.so: $(OBJ_DIR)
    $(CC) - shared -o $(OBJ_DIR)
```

Comment: There are several things wrong with this makefile. I suggest you start with the object files; write a makefile that can build the object files correctly, before you worry about the library.

Comment: @Beta But object files are getting created right at bin location whenever I run make.

Comment: Yes, object files are being created. Have you tried using them? They're not what you think they are.

Comment: @Beta Okay sir I will try and rewrite the MakeFile again. Thanks for advise